# How to convert xml to idml

Tags: perl

I want convert xml to idml file using by perl script.

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <catalog>
         <book id="bk101">
             <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
             <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
             <genre>Computer</genre>
             <price>44.95</price>
             <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
             <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
         </book>
     </catalog>
```

please if any module for idml let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The next time you ask the "is there a module for X" question, **look at [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) first**. In this case, a simple [search](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=IDML;s=0) yields two hits; however the [module (`Image::ExifTool`)](http://search.cpan.org/~exiftool/Image-ExifTool-9.01/lib/Image/ExifTool.pod) only supports [read access](http://search.cpan.org/~exiftool/Image-ExifTool-9.01/lib/Image/ExifTool.pod#DESCRIPTION) to IDML files. So the answer is *no*, there is no appropriate module.

If you have too much time on your hands and if this is legally possible for you, you could try to reverse engineer the target format. In this scenario, Perl would be a glue language at the most, and you would be doing most of the work in XSLT transforms.